# Selected value of one component should be populate in another component using react native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

Here is my scenario.
 Using GetObjectField component I am populating a TextInput ,onFocus of
 the TextInput moving to another component using navigator push method
 there i populate a object list using GenericSummary component.When i select the object that object
 should be replace to the GetObjectField TextInput

```
var GetObjectField = React.createClass({
              getInitialState:function(){
                             return {textValue:""};
              },
              changeState:function(text){
                    var self=this;//here also i am getting text value but i am unable to do the setState
                    self.setState({textValue: text }); 
              },
              view:function(value){
                  this.changeState(value);//Here i am getting selected object value
              }
              render : function(){
                    return (<View>
                               <TextInput id={key}  style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.textValue} placeholder="select object"     onFocus={getDataFromDB.bind(this,this.view)} />

        </View>)
              }
})
function getDataFromDB(fillObject,ev){
             var target=ev;
             this.props.navigator.push({
                   id:'LookupComponent',
                   name:'LookupComponent',
                   fillObject : fillObject,
                   target:target,
              })
}
var LookupComponent=React.createClass({
             renderScene:function(route, navigator) {
                       var self=this
                       var target = this.props.target;
                       var fillObject=this.props.fillObject;
                     return (
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.fillData.bind(this,item.value[refKey],fillObject, target,self.props.navigator)} underlayColor="#ffa456" navigator = {self.props.navigator}>
                       <View >
                         <GenericSummary  record={item.value}  recordId={item.id} org={self.props.org} navigator = {self.props.navigator}/> 
                       </View>
</TouchableHighlight>)
              },
             render:function() {
                    return(<Navigator
                        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
                        navigator={this.props.navigator}
                        navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar style={styles.navBarStyle} routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapperPopUp}  />
          } />)
  }

})
function fillData(data,fillObject,nav,ev){
      nav.pop();//when pop the component the getObjectField component is rerendering again
      if(typeof fillObject != undefined){
          fillObject(rowData,target,data);
       }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When click on TextInput i moving to another scene there i populate list . when select the value in the list i need to populate that value to the previous component of TextInput

Answer (score 1):

You can use the route object in the render scene method to pass extra information about the scene you are about to navigate, and then pass that extra information to your new scene through its props. Looks like you are already passing the fillObject to your route object, so you can access it in the render method like below..

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === "LookupComponent") {
      return (
        <GenericSummary  fillObject={route.fillObject} /> 
      )
    }  
}
```

Comment: <GenericSummary  fillObject={route.fillObject} />  using this how can i fill the selected value to the TextInput of GetObjectfield.

Comment: can you not the set the textValue state in the GetObjectField scene in the getDataFromDB function ?